# SSRS page footer

Tags: reporting-services

I am making a report using Visual studio / Reporting services 2008.  The report needs to display a patient's medical record on every page footer.  It needs to be formatted as a table, but one can't place tables in footers.  I attempted to just use a bunch of text boxes, but they don't align consistently.  For example, in the VS preview the boxes will be aligned fine but when I deploy to the server and view them in the reportviewer their alignment changes.

1.)  Is there a way to fake a table in the footer?
-or
2.)  Is there a suggested way to align a bunch of text boxes so that they render consistently?

Answer (score 1):

in footer and header section only allows: textbox, line, image, rectangle

do not overlap textbo

Comment: I ended up just putting an image of a table at the bottom of the report and overlaying the textboxes where needed.